# Polytopes generated as the convex hull of the orbit of a finite reflection group acting on a given vector

Tags: reference-request, polytopes

Consider a finite reflection group acting on $\mathbb{R}^N$. Pick a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and look at the convex hull of its orbit. This is a polytope.

There are some interesting particular cases. For example, the unit $l_1$ ball can be seen as the convex hull of the orbit of the vector $(1, 0, \ldots, 0)$ under the action of the group of signed permutations. Likewise, the $l_\infty$ can be seen as the convex hull of the orbit of the vector $(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ under the same action.

Are these polytopes well studied? What can be said about them? I would appreciate some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are well-studied. The creation of a polytope as the convex hull of the orbit of a point under a finite reflection group is known as [Wythoff's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff_construction), and the resulting polytopes are called "Wythoffian".

It is extensively discussed in the work of Coxeter, for instance in [*Regular Polytopes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Polytopes_%28book%29), his 1934 paper "Discrete Groups generated by Reflections" ([DOI 10.2307/1968753](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968753)), and his 1935 paper "Wythoff's Construction for Uniform Polytopes" ([DOI 10.1112/plms/s2-38.1.327](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-38.1.327)).

All Wythoffian polytopes are vertex-transitive, and the Wythoffian polytopes include all the polytopes whose reflection group acts transitively on the vertices (i.e. not the polytopes which are vertex-transitive only with rotations.) Almost all the known [uniform polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polytope) are Wythoffian, and these are usually the ones of most interest.